# Explicit form of recursive function representing marginal cost

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion, recursive-algorithms

I am selling a printing service and I would like to charge marginally less for an additional print compared with the average cost of each print given the current quantity. My recursive rule representing the total charge for X+1 given X is therefore:

$$f(x+1) = \left(\frac{f(x)}{x}\times d\right) + f(x)$$
$$f(0) = 0; f(1) = C$$
$${d \; \epsilon \; \mathbb{R}\; | \;0<d<1}$$

My WooCommerce site won't let me use a recursive rule so I was wondering if there is an explicit approximation of this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for an approximation. Note that our recursion can be restated as
$$f(x+1)=\left(\frac{d}x+1\right)f(x)$$
Hence, by applying this formula $x$ times, we have that (for $x\ge0$)
$$\begin{align}
f(x+1)
&=C\cdot\prod_{k=1}^x\left(\frac{d}k+1\right)\\
&=C\cdot\prod_{k=1}^x\left(\frac{d+k}k\right)\\
&=C\cdot\frac{(d+x)(d+x-1)\cdots(d+1)}{x!}\\
&=C\binom{d+x}{x}\\
\end{align}$$
Hence we have the closed form
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}C\binom{d+x-1}{x-1}&x\ge1\\0&x=0\end{cases}$$

Comment: Nicely done. I will note that, If one takes $\binom{n}{m}=0$ for integer $m<0$, then the $x=0$ case at the end is superfluous. But that's a matter of conventions, so your pointing it out explicitly is still sensible.

Comment: @Semiclassical I wasn't completely sure how such binomial coefficients were defined thanks.

Comment: @PeterForeman This is exactly what I need. Thanks!